# Export meeting data from Microsoft Teams for a set of employees

Tags: microsoft-teams

For a given set of employees, I want to be able to find all the meetings that they attended during specified duration. The meetings may have attendees from outside this set of employees which would get ignored. An alternate acceptable solution is to get the time spent by each employee in meetings with a start and end time (not necessarily meeting wise data).

I looked at MS Teams Graph API but it does not seem to have such an API. Other potential option provided by MS Teams may be through an Excel export or Kafka stream but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to export the data from MS Teams (and all of this should run in automated way without any manual intervention)?

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs for the exact ask. There is no API to give the total time spent by user in all meetings, however you can check the following APIs to get the attendance interval[includes joinDateTime,leaveDateTime,durationInSeconds] of attendees for a particular meeting.

1. [Get meetingAttendanceReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. [List attendanceRecords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attendancerecord-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)